# Register a candidate in database only for current user to see

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm making a dating/Matchmaker app in flask/python, I've got users register in db and each users has the possibility to add a new candidate and grow their list, the thing is every user see the same list of registered candidates where I only want them to see who they added themselves. Any Ideas ? I think its a relationship thing with db but I'm maybe wrong. Thanks

```
class User(db.Model, flask_login.UserMixin): # db.Model is required if you want to create an SQL model

    # Every attribute is a class variable

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)

    mail = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    password = db.Column(db.String(64))
    boolean = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

class Candidate(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key = True)
    sexe = db.Column(db.String(15))
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(64))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer())
    mail = db.Column(db.String(64))
    height = db.Column(db.Integer())
    location = db.Column(db.String(64))
    phone = db.Column(db.Integer())
    nationality = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

That's my route for adding a new candidate

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET","POST"])
def addnew():
    form = forms.Candidate()
    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            sexe = form.sexe.data
            firstname = form.firstname.data
            lastname = form.lastname.data
            mail = form.mail.data
            age = form.age.data
            height = form.height.data
            location = form.location.data
            phone = form.phone.data
            nationality = form.nationality.data
            origin = form.origin.data
            father_job = form.father_job.data
            mother_job = form.mother_job.data
            father_origin = form.father_origin.data
            mother_origin = form.mother_origin.data
            school = form.school.data
            future_job = form.future_job.data
            eye_color = form.eye_color.data
            hair_color = form.hair_color.data
            body = form.body.data
            
                    
            newCandidate = models.Candidate(firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, age=age,height=height,location=location,
                                    phone=phone, nationality=nationality,origin=origin, father_job=father_job,
                                    mother_job=mother_job, father_origin=father_origin, mother_origin=mother_origin,
                                    school=school,mail=mail, future_job=future_job, eye_color=eye_color,hair_color=hair_color,
                                    body=body
                                   )
            db.session.add(newCandidate)
            db.session.commit()
            flask.flash("You added a new candidate successfully", "success")
        else:
            flask.flash("You haven't fill the entire form correctly, try again !", "danger")
    
    return flask.render_template("candidate.html", form=form)
```

Comment: see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many

Comment: can't you develop a bit ?

Comment: 1. add `user_id = Column(ForeignKey(User.id))` to `Candidate`.

2. add `user = relationship(User, backref="candidates")`.

3. when you query for the Candidates, you can apply the filter like: `user_candidates = session.query(Candidate).join(User).filter(User.id == my_user_id)` or use [`with_parent`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_parent)